# Griffon view - can I bind to to array element

Tags: view, binding, griffon

In a model I have ..

```
@Bindable contentList = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','J','K','L','M']
```

In a view i have

```
def offset = 0

2.times { outer ->
  6.times { inner ->
     panel(background: Color.white,
           border: BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black),
           constraints: inner.equals(5) ? 'grow,wrap' : 'grow') {
           label(text: bind {model.contentList[offset++]},
                    font: new Font("Sans Serif",
                    Font.PLAIN, 18))
          }
     }
 }
```

On initial loading this works fine but when I try and update an element in the array in a controller 
it's not reflected in the screen   .. Is there a way to bind to an array element ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ObservableList` for this purpose.  For example, in the model, you can declare `contentList` as:

```
ObservableList contentList = new ObservableList(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 
   'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M'])
```

If you bind to the `content` property of `ObservableList`, you will be notified when it is changed.  You can then use a `converter` to retrieve the proper value based on certain index, for example:

```
def offset = 0
def c = { o, v -> v[o] }
2.times { outer ->
   6.times { inner ->
       label(text: bind('content', source: model.contentList, 
                        converter: c.curry(offset++)))
   }
}
```

Comment: as a supplementary , can you explain the bind statement (where does the 'content' field come from) and the use of the curried closure ?

Comment: `content` is a bounded property of `ObservableList` (https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/util/ObservableList.java#L59).  I used curry to make every converter's closures remember their current `offset` or otherwise they will always use the latest value of `offset`.